# gwt-maven-plugin can't compile because of "No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl.SizeValidatorForString;"

Tags: java, maven, gwt, jar

I'm using client-side validation in my `GWT` web app, and `Maven` as a build tool. Running in dev mode doesn't cause any problems. Now I want to build the project with `Maven`, but get multiple errors such as follows:

```
[ERROR] Line 52: No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl.SizeValidatorForString; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 52: No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl.SizeValidatorForCollection; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 52: No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl.SizeValidatorForMap; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 75: No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl.NotNullValidator; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 83: No source code is available for type org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

I wish `gwt-maven-plugin` could see jar source file **hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar** while compiling the project. How to manage this resource to make it work? I've tried to put **hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar** into `src/main/resources` directory, but it doesn't seem to work.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.szybieka.tarantula</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>tarantula</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Tarantula</name>
    <url>http://github.com/shebeko/tarantula</url>

    <properties>
        <gwt.version>2.5.1</gwt.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/lib/json-20090211.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Catcha from local repository -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code</groupId>
            <artifactId>captcha</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson JSON processor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Core  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.szybieka.tarantula</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Location -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.szybieka.tarantula</groupId>
            <artifactId>location</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DataSource -->     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <finalName>tarantula</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessor>com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.RfValidator</annotationProcessor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
                        <artifactId>requestfactory-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/war</warSourceDirectory>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/**,WEB-INF/lib/gwt-servlet*,gwtia_requestfactory_*/**</warSourceExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <modules>
                                <param>com.szybieka.tarantula.gwt.MainModule</param>
                            </modules>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
                        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
                        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>




        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

After adding **hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar** hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar  *mvn clean install* results in:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Tarantula 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ tarantula ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ tarantula ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 50 source files to /home/adam-szybieka/workspace/tarantula/parent/web/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/adam-szybieka/workspace/tarantula/parent/web/src/main/java/com/szybieka/tarantula/gwt/client/proxy/PrincipalProxy.java:[3,43] package org.hibernate.validator.constraints does not exist
[ERROR] /home/adam-szybieka/workspace/tarantula/parent/web/src/main/java/com/szybieka/tarantula/gwt/client/proxy/PrincipalFormProxy.java:[3,43] package org.hibernate.validator.constraints does not exist
[ERROR] /home/adam-szybieka/workspace/tarantula/parent/web/src/main/java/com/szybieka/tarantula/gwt/client/proxy/PrincipalProxy.java:[14,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NotEmpty
  location: interface com.szybieka.tarantula.gwt.client.proxy.PrincipalProxy
[ERROR] /home/adam-szybieka/workspace/tarantula/parent/web/src/main/java/com/szybieka/tarantula/gwt/client/proxy/PrincipalProxy.java:[19,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NotEmpty
  location: interface com.szybieka.tarantula.gwt.client.proxy.PrincipalProxy
[ERROR] /home/adam-szybieka/workspace/tarantula/parent/web/src/main/java/com/szybieka/tarantula/gwt/client/proxy/PrincipalFormProxy.java:[9,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NotEmpty
  location: interface com.szybieka.tarantula.gwt.client.proxy.PrincipalFormProxy
[ERROR] /home/adam-szybieka/workspace/tarantula/parent/web/src/main/java/com/szybieka/tarantula/gwt/client/proxy/PrincipalFormProxy.java:[14,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NotEmpty
  location: interface com.szybieka.tarantula.gwt.client.proxy.PrincipalFormProxy
[ERROR] /home/adam-szybieka/workspace/tarantula/parent/web/src/main/java/com/szybieka/tarantula/gwt/client/proxy/PrincipalFormProxy.java:[19,6] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NotEmpty
  location: interface com.szybieka.tarantula.gwt.client.proxy.PrincipalFormProxy
[ERROR] /home/adam-szybieka/workspace/tarantula/parent/web/src/main/java/com/szybieka/tarantula/gwt/client/proxy/PrincipalProxy.java:[15,12] java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:396)
....................................................
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your pom.xml it's a little difficult to say but my first assumption is that you forgot to add a dependency for hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar in your pom or there is a versioning problem. Could you post your pom?

Got it:

You have this dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

which is the 4.2.0.Final jar BUT you do not have the 4.2.0.Final-sources.jar

Add the dependency for final-sources and you should have your answer.

Comment: So here is `pom.xml`. Actually, I've tried to add **hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar** in pom along with **hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar**, but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you clean and build as well?

Comment: Get the GA sources as well and make sure they are in your classpaths for both client and server

Comment: I'm not sure, but seems it's wrong to add both **hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar** and **hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar** dependencies to pom. I've updated error stack trace.

Comment: why are you using <scope>="system" ?

Comment: I can't figure out, how to let `Maven` know where to locate **hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar**, so I'm using explicit path with `<systemPath>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You need Hibernate Validator 4.1 (not 4.0, not 4.2).

See https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7661

Note: obviously, for server-side validation, you could use whichever version of Hibernate Validator you want.

Comment: Thanks for answer! After I've replaced Hibernate Validator **4.2.0.Final** with **4.1.0.Final** in `/war/WEB-INF/lib`, `GWT` compiles project successfully. But how to configure `pom.xml` to make Maven to build the project?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have in your classpath both:hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar  and hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar

just add following to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    <classifier>sources</classifier>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```